# How can I remove exception "Predefined type 'ValueTuple`2' must be a struct" when debugging?

Tags: debugging, exception, tuples, visual-studio-2017, c#-7.0

I started using the new tuple feature in c# 7.0 but I noticed that neither in the function that returns a tuple nor in its caller is possible to check the variable values in debug mode. Instead an exception is shown:

```
$exception  error CS8182: Predefined type 'ValueTuple`2' must be a struct.
```

Is there a way to get rid of that glitch and debug normally?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems a bug that Microsoft has fixed but it will be available in a future update (2017)
https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/16930

Answer (score 3):

It is a bug in the current version of System.ValueTuple. To workaround it till MS releases the fix, downgrade the package version from 4.3.0 to a pre-release one.

Comment: Looks like it is now fixed in System.ValueTuple 4.3.1